# Unable to filter the data for multiple time selections by dimensions

Tags: filter, mdx

I am new in MDX, i have a problem with my MDX query.

**Calculated Member Logic:**

```
SUM((OPENINGPERIOD([Date].[YQMD].[Year],[Date].[YQMD].[Month].&[2010-12-01T00:00:00]):[Date].[YQMD].Currentmember),[Measures].[Paid Amt])
```

**Mdx Logic EX:**

With Member

```
 [MEASURES].[Received_Amount]
AS
SUM((OPENINGPERIOD([Date].[YQMD].[Year],[Date].[YQMD].[Month].&[2010-12-01T00:00:00]):[Date].[YQMD].Currentmember)
,[Measures].[Paid Amt])
SELECT {[MEASURES].[Received_Amount]} On Columns
,[Date].[YQMD].[Year].members On Rows
From [Financial]
```

If i select multiple time periods in Rows, the query working fine.

but if select multiple periods in where clause it is not responding.

With Member

```
 [MEASURES].[Received_Amount]
AS
SUM((OPENINGPERIOD([Date].[YQMD].[Year],[Date].[YQMD].[Month].&[2010-12-01T00:00:00]):    [Date].[YQMD].Currentmember)
,[Measures].[Paid Amt])
SELECT {[MEASURES].[Received_Amount]} On Columns
,[Speciality].[Specialty Name].[Specialty Name].members On Rows
From [Financial]
Where {[Date].[YQMD].[Year].&[2012-01-01T00:00:00],[Date].[YQMD].[Year].&[2013-01-01T00:00:00]}
```

**Note:**
Each of them is considered from the minimum date in the database to the selected time.
And also the data has to be filtered with respect to each drill down dimension.

If select multiple time periods the same formula has to be applied with respect to the dimensions.

Kindly help me to get out of this problem

Best Regards,
Nagendra

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem that you are describing as "where clause it is not responding" is due to the fact that `CurrentMember` returns an error in case you have multi selects, as there is no single current member. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/11/18/writing-multiselect-friendly-mdx-calculations.aspx and http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/01/13/multiselect-friendly-mdx-for-calculations-looking-at-current-coordinate.aspx for some approaches how to deal with this.